# How to get all distinct values of field in elasticsearch without specifying size

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic search terms API returns 10 distinct values by default or asks for some size. How to get all distinct values without specifying some specific size. I don't know the exact or approximate order of size, so can't pass that.

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22136 and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size

Comment: What is good way? Use scoll API with composite aggregation or fetch cardinality and set size in normal terms query.

Comment: well i suggest to manually set size to INTEGER.Max_value in the query.